# Sensor data transmission without using a microcontroller?

Tags: microcontroller, embedded, uart, serial, radio

What is the most traditional approach to getting sensor data onto a radio from an embedded device pcb that doesn’t utilize a microcontroller?

Up until now, we’ve been utilizing a convenient firmware on the radio that accesses discrete GPIO data directly wired to the radio’s IO and it automatically constructs everything on the UART for us. Now we need to load information that is not within the sampling capability of the old radio, but utilizes the same traditional UART for sending commands and streaming data.

I know there are probably standalone UART IC’s that I assume are serial setting configurable. Is this recommendable, or should I not waste my time? The benefits to no uC would be no need for new code and less strain on the PCB layout redesign, if we even have the space.

I would likely need bidirectional capability later.

Thanks

Comment: Convert the data (assuming from a single sensor) to an audio frequency and modulate the transmitter (AM or FM) with that. Simple and easy to decode. Anything more than that, use an MCU.

Comment: Harris CDP6402D or CDP6402DC is an ancient standalone UART IC in 40-pin wide DIP package. Parallel 8-bit data in/data out. Hardware strobes to trigger tx/rx action. Can buy from Rochester Electronics via digikey.com. Much bigger and slightly more expensive than a modern microcontroller. 5V only, no 3V. Requires building a bespoke state machine to support sending more than one byte of data. Last time I saw this part used was in 1991 on a design that dated from 1987. Would recommend use an MCU instead.

Comment: Just get some SO-8 MCU. You could even pick a SOT-23 one if you want to be silly. Just check the spec of the RC oscillator and pick one with <3% inaccuracy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only remotely sensible solution is to use an MCU.

That was true last week when someone asked a remarkably similar question, 
and it remains true today.

MCUs are cheaper and more flexible than all but the simplest combinations of building block logic, and have the added benefit of drastically expanding the sorts of radios and radio protocols which you can consider, letting you add checksums or cryptographic security, letting you go to low power modes in between readings, letting you build in self-test diagnostics, readily tag transmissions with a unique ID, even giving you the option of storing sensor calibration in the device rather than a database...

An MCU would also typically make the PCB layout *easier* rather than harder, because at least if your layout and firmware people are on speaking terms, you can often put functions on any one of a number of pins in order to make the layout simple; conversely with building block logic or special function ICs you often have to use one particular pin without a choice.

Comment: "remotely sensible" 8-/

Answer (score 3):

> getting sensor data onto a radio from an embedded device pcb that doesn’t utilize a microcontroller?

Then the solution will look like a weather balloon or satellite from the 1970's, with lots of logic hardware to encode data into a specific radio protocol, which these days would better fit a CPLD... which is another programmable device.

> less strain on the PCB layout redesign

A microcontroller can be reprogrammed, which makes your design a lot more flexible. So yeah, sure, you have to do the layout job, but later if you want to add features you may be able to do it without changing the hardware, which is a plus.

> I would likely need bidirectional capability later.

See above, if you plan for it in your current design then you could add bidirectional capability with a firmware upgrade.

Note: your question sounds like your radio module already has a microcontroller, so perhaps you can simply use it and modify its firmware.